# Share laptop's Wi-Fi with a LAN connection and a mobile device

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, connection-sharing

OS: Windows 7 64bit

I want to share my laptop's internet connection between my PC and my Android device.
But I can only do one of them at a time.

1. The laptop is connected to internet wirelessly.
2. The PC is connected to the laptop using a Ethernet cable and internet is shared between them.
3. I want to connect my mobile device to my laptop by making the laptop into a Wi-Fi hotspot.

PC (Ethernet) ==> Laptop (connected to net by Wi-Fi) <== Mobile device (Wi-Fi hotspot)

I have 3 connections in my laptop:

- Wireless Network Connection (internet - shared)
- Local area connection (PC)
- Wireless Network Connection 2 (Wi-Fi hotspot)

Every time I have to disable either the LAN to get the Wi-Fi hotspot working, or disable the Wi-Fi hotspot to get LAN working.

How can I share so I can use both at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Use connectify.me software or adhoc internet connection.

Although you might need a Pro version of the software to share wi-fi internet.